# XLOOKUP function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to sum all hours for a person, see the example picture.

[Excel Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJLqG.png)

I was wondering if XLOOKUP could be used for this? But it seems like XLOOKUP is unable to sum vertically, when the person appears more than once?
I would like the function to search for Tim and return 30 (10 + 20).
Is XLOOKUP not suited for this?

Comment: You only need to use sumif for this case, as far as I know xlookup is only used to look up the value https://support.office.com/en-us/article/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929

Answer (score 1):

You likely want SUMIF().

```
=SUMIF(B1:B3, "Tim", C1:C3)
```